# Would ServerValue.timestamp() work even if there is no connection?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I am wondering if Firestore's ServerValue.timestamp() will return a value from its callback even when offline? Would it be a wise choice then to use ServerValue.timestamp() to track when a (potentially offline) file is modified? Thanks

Comment: It's just a timestamp value, I wouldn't bind yourself to the firebase timestamp unless order of delivery is critical. Just use the default iOS `Date` class

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "return a value from its callback".  ServerValue.timestamp() is a function that returns a static token that gets interpreted on the server.   It will return that same token value no matter if the client app is online or offline. Is there some more specific scenario that you're wondering about?

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson, thanks. Since the token is interpreted by the server, I'm wondering if it possible to get a return value (milliseconds) when there is no connection available.

Answer (score 2):

`ServerValue.timestamp()` is a function that returns a static token that gets interpreted on the server when it's written to a field of a document.  The token itself is meaningless otherwise.

If you want a Timestamp object with current time reckoned by the clock on the client device, simply call [Timestamp.init()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Timestamp#init).

For more information about how server timestamps work that isn't fully covered by the documentation, read [this article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/the-secrets-of-firestore-fieldvalue-servertimestamp-revealed-29dd7a38a82b).